# Why does smooth scrollBy only work first time?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am using the following code on a [website](http://www.coffeebeansandotherlies.com/) to imitate smooth scrolling:

```
function scrollWindow() {
    // window.scrollBy(1040,0)
    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollBy(104, 0);
        if( window.pageXOffset >= 1040 ) clearInterval(timerID);
    }, 10);
}
```

However, after clicking Scroll (the scrollWindow function) the page scrolls 1040 like it should.

Any subsequent time, it does not work, unless i manually scroll back to the beginning.

Would i be right in thinking that `if( window.pageXOffset >= 1040 )` is canceling it because although it hasn't *moved* 1040, it is past that point on the page?

If so, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assessment is correct; but it could be corrected with a twist in the approach:

```
function scrollWindow() {
    var scrolledSoFar = 0;
    var scrollStep = 104;
    var scrollEnd  = 1040;
    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollBy(scrollStep, 0);
        scrolledSoFar += scrollStep;
        if( scrolledSoFar >= scrollEnd ) clearInterval(timerID);
    }, 10);
}
```

**Update**
Another pitfall in the code is that you are executing `scrollBy` before checking for the condition. So on your page, even after you have scrolled past 1040, clicking `scroll` will move the page by one `scrollStep` amount. To prevent that, this order is better:

```
function scrollWindow() {
    var scrolledSoFar = 0;
    var scrollStep = 104;
    var scrollEnd  = 1040;
    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        if( scrolledSoFar < scrollEnd ) {
            window.scrollBy(scrollStep, 0);
            scrolledSoFar += scrollStep;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timerID);
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Ah, this sort of approach didn't even occur to me, to track how far it had scrolled like that.

Comment: @LewisGoddard, just added an update. You may want to consider this too.